# APM: command not found

Tags: command-line, software-installation, 18.04, snap, atom

I installed **Atom** using **Snap**.

Then I tried to install **Hydrogen** as an addon for **Atom**.

This output appears -

```
apm install hydrogen

Command 'apm' is available in '/snap/bin/apm'
The command could not be located because '/snap/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
apm: command not found
```

Comment: as the error printed, just do `export PATH=$PATH:/snap/bin` and you will be able to remove this error; ifnot, it will be another one (WARNING: `export` is limited at 1 terminal, if you change of window or close it, the `export` would be erased)

Answer (score 1):

Open Atom and select *Settings* tab -> click the blue *Install* button located on the left side of the Settings pane. Under the **Featured Packages** section Hydrogen is the first package in the list because it is the most popular Atom package. Click the blue *Install* button to install it in Atom. Alternatively you can also search for Hydrogen in the search box in the **Install Packages** section of the Settings pane.

Answer (score 0):

Like it says - apm is not in your PATH. Add it like so:

`export PATH=$PATH:/snap/bin/apm`

Put it in ~/.profile - to run at terminal startup if you wish