# How to access apm for io.atom.Atom flatpak

Tags: flatpak, atom

### What is the proper way for accessing apm (Atom package manager) for flatpakked Atom?

I couldn't find the answer searching by DDG or Google. Slightly related [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1063838/apm-command-not-found).

I can run Atom itself via:

```
flatpak run io.atom.Atom
```

One way I can run apm is via:

```
/var/lib/flatpak/app/io.atom.Atom/current/active/files/share/atom/resources/app/apm/node_modules/.bin/apm
```

But this hardly seems normal. Is there some more reasonable/nice/clean/proper way to do this? Some things that don't work:

```
apm
```

```
flatpak run io.atom.Atom.apm
```

```
flatpak run io.atom.Apm
```

```
flatpak run io.atom.Atom --apm
```

```
/var/lib/flatpak/app/io.atom.Atom/current/active/files/bin/apm
```

The last path exists but tells me:

```
/var/lib/flatpak/app/io.atom.Atom/current/active/files/bin/apm: 5: exec: /app/bin/apm-real: not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
flatpak run --command=apm io.atom.Atom
```

or more specifically:

```
flatpak run --command=apm io.atom.Atom install packagename1 packagename2
```

The answer was in these two ([1](https://github.com/flathub/io.atom.Atom/issues/3), [2](https://github.com/flathub/io.atom.Atom/issues/20)) closed issues on [io.atom.Atom github page](https://github.com/flathub/io.atom.Atom).